# Conjunctions in negation: "no/neither" and "and/or/nor"

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, negation

When I have these facts,

1. French coins were not found in the ruin.
2. German coins were not found in the ruin.

which of these sentences are grammatically correct?

1.

> No French and German coins were found in the ruin.

2.

> No French or German coins were found in the ruin.

3.

> No french nor German coins were found in the ruin.

I think 1 is correct but I'm not sure.  By the way, I can also say

> Neither German nor French coins were found in the ruin.

Also, when you have an additional fact

3. Italian coins were not found in the ruin

which of these statements are grammatically correct?

1.

> No French, German and Italian coins were found in the ruin.

2.

> No French, German or Italian coins were found in the ruin.

3.

> None of French, German and Italian coins were found in the ruin.

4.

> None of French, German or Italian coins were found in the ruin.

Thanks,

Comment: Only 2. is idiomatic. You will occasionally find constructions like 4., but they are rare and klunky.

Comment: In casual conversation, you will hear people say "*There weren't any* French, German, or Italian coins found in the ruin."  In writing, where concision is a goal, you'd see "No French, German, ...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sentences

***And*** **Problem**

> 1) **No** French **and** German coins were found in the ruin.
>
> No French, German and Italian coins were found in the ruin.
>   None of French, German and Italian coins were found in the ruin.

can possibly mean coins coproduced by the French **and** the Germans or coins coproduced by the Germans **and** the Italians. In the examples of three different coins, this can be solved by punctuation, adding a ','(comma) before the **and**

> No French, German**,** and Italian coins were found in the ruin.
>   None of French, German**,** and Italian coins were found in the ruin.

these would have the meaning you want as in #2

**The Correct One**

> 2) **No** French **or** German coins were found in the ruin.
>
> **No** French, German **or** Italian coins were found in the ruin.
>   No French, German, or Italian coins were found in the ruin.

means both French coins and German coins and Italian coins were not found

***Nor*** **Problem**

> 3) **No** french **nor** German coins were found in the ruin.

is not quite right and should be

> 3) **Neither** French **nor** German coins were found in the ruin.
>    **Neither** French **nor** German **nor** Italian coins were found in the ruin.

**nor** is usually paired with **neither** as is a **set combination**, and has the same meaning as #2

***Klunky*** **Problem** *(as per @StoneyB)*

> **None of** French, German or Italian coins were found in the ruin.

is correct but not often used.

Answer (score 2):

#2. #1 would imply no coins that were simultaneously French *and* German were found.

In the second group, also #2; I don't know if 4 is grammatically correct, but I've never heard anyone use such constructs.